# How to get the coordinate of a touch event

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

How do I determine where the user touched in my view?

Comment: What do you mean by get the coordinate in UIImage? You mean to get the (x, y) of a specific point inside an image or you want to get the (x, y) of the image inside a UIView

Comment: i'am sorry, i mean get the (x, y) of a specific point inside an image.
thnx

Comment: You specify a point by its (x, y) co-ordinates, so you would need to already have them. What are you trying to get? Please describe what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: is there any method such as getCoordinate or something else.??
i just want to know the co-ordinates of image, when user touch it. it's possible to doing like that.??

actually i want to make the annotation in my image (which jpeg extension) i think its impossible to doing that with MapKit, so maybe if i know the co-ordinate of my image, i can make the annotation simulate with add the subview at that co-ordinate.

help me please.. :(
thnx

Comment: OK, so the image itself is irrelevant; you want to know where the user touched.

Comment: i got it dude,, with knowing the pixel of UIImage, by following this nice example : http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2009/9/24/getting-at-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-for-iphone-dev.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see `- (UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point` found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20181012154604/http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color

I would rewrite it as a category method on UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint origin = view.frame.origin;
```